# Нету провайдера SQLite в Мастере моделей EDM при выборе источника данных

Tags: c#, sqlite

День добрый. Поставил значит ORM EF6, поставил SQLite, а при выборе источника данных кроме SQL Server больше ничего нету, не могу понять, что делать дальше. Помогите пожалуйста. Использую microsoft visual studio 2017 15.3.2

Comment: Поддержка SQLite "из коробки" есть только у EF Core, только там нужно использовать подход Code First.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста по подробней.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поддержка работы, что называется из коробки, с SQLite есть у Entity Framework Core. Единственный нюанс это то, что в этой версии нет подхода Schema First, то есть у вас не будет возможности разработать сначала модель EDM, а потом уже базу. Зато есть вариант работы Code First или Database First + есть поддержка миграций. В качестве иллюстрации рассмотрим наипростейший пример  Code First без миграций.

Создадим БД "Авторы и Книги" с отношением таблиц "многие-ко-многим", т.е. У автора может быть написано много книг и книга, в свою очередь, может иметь несколько авторов.

Создайте пустое решение

[image: Пример создания пустого решения]
Начнем работу с создания библиотеки .Net Standard

[image: пример создания проекта библиотеки]

Здесь мы создадим классы модели и интерфейсы репозитория и `UnityOfWork`
вот такой класс Автора

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<AuthorBook> Books { get; set; }

    //ctor
    public Author()
    {
        Name = "<?>";
        Books = new List<AuthorBook>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id}: {Name}";
    }
}
```

вот такой класс Книги

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }

    public virtual List<AuthorBook> Authors { get; set; }

    //ctor
    public Book()
    {
        Title = "<?>";
        Authors = new List<AuthorBook>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id}:{Title}";
    }
}
```

И для связи между ними нам придется создать в явном виде класс АвторКнига с указанием свойства для первичного ключа, составной ключ здесь создать можно только вручную с помощью `Fluen API`, но мы хотим простоты и автоматизма, потому делаем свойство Id.

```
public class AuthorBook
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }

    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь создадим интерфейс Репозитория с набором CRUD методов

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Get();
    Task<TEntity> Get(int id);

    Task<bool> Add(TEntity entity);
    Task<bool> Update(TEntity entity);
    Task<bool> Delete(int id);
}
```

Теперь репозиторий для Автора

```
public interface IAuthorRepository : IRepository<Author>
{
    Task<Author> GetByName(string name);
}
```

и для Книги

```
public interface IBookRepository : IRepository<Book>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Book>> Find(Expression<Func<Book, bool>> predicate);
    Task<Book> GetWithAuthors(int id);
}
```

Ну и для `UnityOfWork`

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IAuthorRepository Authors { get; }
    IBookRepository Books { get; }

    Task<int> Commit();
}
```

Теперь создадим еще один проект библиотеки (добавьте в References ссылку на предыдущий проект библиотеки) и установите nuget пакет
 `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` в эту новую библиотеку.
Начнем с создания класса для контекста

```
public class ExDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _databasePath;

    //ctor
    public ExDbContext(string databasePath)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(databasePath)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(databasePath));

        _databasePath = databasePath;

        //создание/пересоздание БД
        //Database.EnsureDeleted(); //удаление БД
        Database.EnsureCreated(); //создание новой пустой БД, если БД не была создана ранее
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={_databasePath}");
    }

    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AuthorBook> AutorsBooks { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь класс репозитория для Автора

```
public class AuthorRepository : IAuthorRepository
{
    private readonly ExDbContext _context;

    //ctor
    public AuthorRepository(ExDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _context = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Author>> Get()
    {
        List<Author> result = null;

        try
        {
            //ToListAsync() прячется в using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
            result = await _context.Authors.ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = new List<Author>();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<Author> Get(int id)
    {
        Author result = null;

        try
        {
            result = await _context.Authors.FindAsync(id);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = new Author();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<Author> GetByName(string name)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

        Author result = null;

        try
        {
            result = await _context.Authors.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Name.Equals(name));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = new Author();
        }

        return result;

    }

    public async Task<bool> Add(Author author)
    {
        if (author == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(author));

        Boolean result = false;

        try
        {
            var tracking = await _context.Authors.AddAsync(author);

            result = tracking.State == EntityState.Added;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Update(Author author)
    {
        if (author == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(author));
        if (author.Id == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(author));

        Boolean result = false;

        try
        {
            var tracking = _context.Authors.Update(author);

            result = tracking.State == EntityState.Modified;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(result);
    }

    public async Task<bool> Delete(int id)
    {
        Boolean result = false;

        try
        {
            Author author = await _context.Authors.FindAsync(id);
            if (author == null) return result;

            var tracking = _context.Authors.Remove(author);

            result = tracking.State == EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Класс репозитория для Книги

```
public class BookRepository : IBookRepository
{
    private readonly ExDbContext _context;

    //ctor
    public BookRepository(ExDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _context = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Book>> Get()
    {
        List<Book> result = null;

        try
        {
            //ToListAsync() прячется в using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
            result = await _context.Books.ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = new List<Book>();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<Book> Get(int id)
    {
        Book result = null;

        try
        {
            result = await _context.Books.FindAsync(id);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = new Book();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<Book> GetWithAuthors(int id)
    {
        Book result = null;

        try
        {
            result = _context.Books
                                   .Include(b => b.Authors)
                                   .ThenInclude(ab => ab.Author)
                                   .ToList()
                                   .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == id);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = new Book();
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(result);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Book>> Find(Expression<Func<Book, bool>> predicate)
    {
        List<Book> result = null;

        try
        {
            result = await _context.Books.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = new List<Book>();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Add(Book book)
    {
        if (book == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(book));

        Boolean result = false;

        try
        {
            var tracking = await _context.Books.AddAsync(book);

            result = tracking.State == EntityState.Added;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Update(Book book)
    {
        if (book == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(book));
        if (book.Id == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(book));

        Boolean result = false;

        try
        {
            var tracking = _context.Books.Update(book);

            result = tracking.State == EntityState.Modified;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(result);
    }

    public async Task<bool> Delete(int id)
    {
        Boolean result = false;

        try
        {
            Book book = await _context.Books.FindAsync(id);
            if (book == null) return result;

            var tracking = _context.Books.Remove(book);

            result = tracking.State == EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Последний штрих, точнее класс такой

```
public class ExDbService : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ExDbContext _context;

    public IAuthorRepository Authors { get; private set; }
    public IBookRepository Books { get; private set; }

    //ctor
    public ExDbService(string fileName)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileName));

        //определяем полный путь к файлу БД
        var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var path = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);

        _context = new ExDbContext(path);
        Authors = new AuthorRepository(_context);
        Books = new BookRepository(_context);
    }


    public async Task<int> Commit()
    {
        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
        Authors = null;
        Books = null;
    }
}
```

Настало время воспользоваться нашими библиотеками. Создадим новый проект типа `WPF`,  в него нужно тоже установить `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`. Добавьте ссылки на наши библиотеки. Приводить весь код этой программы я не буду покажу лишь пример работы

[image: пример работы программы]

и кусок кода где мы запускаем работу с БД

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private const string _FILE_NAME_DB = "authors.sqlite";

    private readonly IMainWindow _mainWindow;
    private IUnitOfWork _dbService;

    //ctor
    public MainViewModel(IMainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        _mainWindow = mainWindow ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mainWindow));
        _dbService = new ExDbService(_FILE_NAME_DB);

        LoadData();
    }

    private async void LoadData()
    {
        ListAuthors = new ObservableCollection<Author>(await _dbService.Authors.Get());
        ListBooks = new ObservableCollection<Book>(await _dbService.Books.Get());
    }

    //...
}
```

файл пустой базы будет создан в момент запуска программы. Весь пример целиком можно скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/Hnv95zgi3QaaDx).